# one sub domain is working but simliar content subdmain in different IP is not working

Tags: linux, apache, dns, vhosts, subdomain-fu

Contents are similar in both subdomains. But one domain is working but the other is not working.

Apache host files.

merchant.clouspos.lk (This is working)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com
        ServerName merchant.cloudpos.lk
        ServerAlias merchant.cloudpos.lk

        ServerAdmin webmaster@et.lk

        RedirectMatch 301 /ipgresponse_dfecVfBuvsdRkY24(.*) /main.html#/paymentprocessing$1

        DocumentRoot /var/www/merchant/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

merchant2.cloudpos.lk (This is redirct to different site)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com
        ServerName merchant2.cloudpos.lk
        ServerAlias merchant2.cloudpos.lk

        ServerAdmin webmaster@et.lk

        RedirectMatch 301 /ipgresponse_dfecVfBuvsdRkY24(.*) /main.html#/paymentprocessing$1

        DocumentRoot /var/www/merchant2/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Please provide a solution for this issue? Source code is same in both subdomains.

Comment: There are no redirects to different site in your Apache configuration, so redirect must be coming form your code.

Comment: I checked with developers, redirect not in there

Comment: can you also provide <VirtualHost *:443> confgis

Comment: I use http only, not https.

Comment: If I open http://merchant2.cloudpos.lk/ in my browser, I do not get any redirect, the page looks fine

Comment: Actually, It wants to similar to merchant.cloudpos.lk but it is different.